# searching for value in an array with a for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am searching for an value from an array in javascript and this is my code.

HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="enter here" id="textvalue">
<button id="checkbutton">check</button>
```

Javascript

```
let arr = ["boy", "cat", "dog"];
let txtval = document.querySelector("#textvalue");
let chkbutt = document.querySelector("#checkbutton");

chkbutt.addEventListener("click", arraycheck);

function arraycheck () {
 for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   if(txtval.value==arr[i]) {
     alert("match found for " + txtval.value)
     }
  else {
   alert("its not there")
    }
 }
}
```

At the moment, I keep getting alert saying "its not there" when I enter "dog". It prints "its not there" twice and then prints "match found for dog".
I would like the alert to show only if the word does not exist in the array. I know it is doing this because I have the if statement in the for loop and each time if the index of the array does not match, it shows the alert. But how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're alerting on every pass of the loop. Instead, use a flag and alert at the end:

```
function arraycheck () {
    var found = false; // *** The flag
    for (var i=0; !found && i<arr.length; i++) {
//                ^^^^^^^^^---- *** Stop looping if we find it
        if (txtval.value==arr[i]) {
            found = true; // *** Set the flag, it was found
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        alert("match found for " + txtval.value);
    } else {
        alert("its not there");
    }
}
```

or we could just use the result of the `==` directly:

```
function arraycheck () {
    var found = false; // *** The flag
    for (var i=0; !found && i<arr.length; i++) {
//                ^^^^^^^^^---- *** Stop looping if we find it
        found = txtval.value==arr[i]; // *** Set the flag if it was found
    }
    if (found) {
        alert("match found for " + txtval.value);
    } else {
        alert("its not there");
    }
}
```

(Side note: Unless you're declaring `i` somewhere you haven't shown, your code is falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *[that's a post on my anemic little blog]*. Declare your variables. I've added declarations for `i` in the examples above.)

---

**However**, there's already a function for that (two, in fact): `includes` (on newer JavaScript engines) and `indexOf` (on older ones):

```
function arrayCheck() {
    var found = arr.includes(txtval.value); // <===
    if (found) {
        alert("match found for " + txtval.value)
    } else {
        alert("its not there")
    }
}
```

or the `found` part of that on older browsers using `indexOf`:

```
var found = arr.indexOf(txtval.value) != -1;
```

---

In a comment you asked:

> I was wondering if you could also stop the loop in my code using "return"?

Yes, that's yet another way to do it in this *specific* case, since exiting the function (with `return`) exits the loop:

```
function arraycheck () {
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (txtval.value==arr[i]) {
            alert("match found for " + txtval.value);
            return;
        }
    }
    alert("its not there");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So many different ways to do things. I was wondering if you could also stop the loop in my code using "return"?

Comment: @craftdeer: Yes, in that specific case, using `return` in the loop would exit the function (and so naturally would exit the loop). So that's yet another option for you, I've added an example of it at the end above.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you everybody. I have learned a lot and need to learn a lot more. Happy New Year.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify using indexOf method,

**`if(arr.indexOf(txtval.value) > -1)`**

**DEMO**

```js
let arr = ["boy", "cat", "dog"];
let txtval = document.querySelector("#textvalue");
let chkbutt = document.querySelector("#checkbutton");

chkbutt.addEventListener("click", arraycheck); 

function arraycheck () {
if(arr.indexOf(txtval.value) > -1)
  {
   alert("match found");
  }
  else {
   alert("its not there");
    }
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="enter here" id="textvalue">
<button id="checkbutton">check</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following with Array's `includes()` in a more simpler and cleaner way:

```js
let arr = ["boy", "cat", "dog"];
let txtval = document.querySelector("#textvalue");
let chkbutt = document.querySelector("#checkbutton");

chkbutt.addEventListener("click", arraycheck);

function arraycheck () {
  if(arr.includes(txtval.value)){
    alert("match found for " + txtval.value)
  }
  else{
    alert("its not there")
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="enter here" id="textvalue">
<button id="checkbutton">check</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable that will turn to true when a match is found. Then if after the loop the variable is still false, then no match has been found.

Or better yet, use lodash filter. It simplifies the looping process.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find the index of your `txtval.value` in the array by using JavaScript `Array` `indexOf()` method.

It takes a input value and output the index number of that value in the `Array` if the value exists.

As javascript array index starts from 0, so if the value exists, the method will return integer(index in the array) value that is greater than -1.

So, in your case,

```
function arraycheck () {
    var index = arr.indexOf(txtval.value);
    if(index > -1){
        //alert for found match
    }else{
        //alert for no match found
    }
}
```